# Visual C# database controller, save button greyed out

Tags: c#, visual-studio, database-design, visual-studio-2012

I've set up a C# project in Visual Studio 2012 express.

To the project I've added a dataset with a few tables. Then I drag the table from the datasourcepanel onto the form. The table shows and the data is there. When i launch the program I can fill out the dataset and everything seems allright. , except that the save button in the default controller (TableBindingNavigator) is greyed out for some reason. I havent changed anything. How come? And what do I do about it?

Comment: is it a mvc project??

Comment: No, it is a standard windows form project

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

Apparently, the save-button comes as disabled by default.

Comment: LOL!! must have been fun for u!!

Comment: Took me 2 hours to figure out hehe